# htaccess rewrite rewrite url with folders after php file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i am trying to get something like this:

```
http://localhost/Engine/admin.php/users/manage
```

to rewrite to something like this:

```
http://localhost/Engine/admin.php?p=users&a=manage
```

i am a beginner with rewrite rules, but i have a basic one here, they cant conflict...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ /Engine/index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

also, if anyone has any improvements for my other rewrite, it would be most helpfull, it rewrites

```
http://localhost/Engine/somepage
```

to:

```
http://localhost/Engine/index.php?page=somepage
```

Answer (score 0):

Your generic rule that matches everything should be listed as last rule. You can improve it by only allowing to match if `.php` is not in the url. For `admin.php` you know how many arguments there should be, so you can simply match the static part of the url with `^Engine/admin\.php/`, then all arguments with `([^/]+)` (match everything but `/`). The last `/?` matches a trailing slash that might or might not be appended.

For more information [read the documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

```
RewriteRule ^Engine/admin\.php/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /Engine/admin.php?p=$1&a=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Engine/.*\.php.*$
RewriteRule ^Engine/(.*)$ /Engine/index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```